# Smallest number in an array python

Tags: python

Trying to find the smallest number in an array that the user inputs. Here's what I have:

```
def main():
   numbers = eval(input("Give me an array of numbers: "))
   smallest = numbers[0]
   for i in range(0,len(numbers),1):
      if (numbers[i] < smallest):
         smallest = numbers[i]
         print("The smallest number is: ", smallest)
main()
```

The result I'm looking for is to be:

```
Give me an array of numbers: [11, 5, 3, 51]
The smallest number is 3
```

Instead, this is what I am getting:

```
Give me an array of numbers: [11, 5, 3, 51]
The smallest number is:  5
The smallest number is:  3
```

Can anyone help me figure out where I am messing up? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you assigned `smallest = numbers[0]` you can change the range in the for-loop to start at index 1 rather than 0. Also, the `step` parameter of range is `1` by default, so not required to specify.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#min):

```
print("The smallest number is: ", min(numbers))
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to print the output only once after the loop finishes.

```
def main():
   numbers = eval(input("Give me an array of numbers: "))
   smallest = numbers[0]
   for i in range(0,len(numbers),1):
      if (numbers[i] < smallest):
         smallest = numbers[i]
   print("The smallest number is: ", smallest)
main()
```

Or use `min()` as Christian suggested.

Comment: Not supposed to use built in functions. Practicing using different patterns, in this case, the extreme pattern.

Comment: @user3518112 If you're operating under constraints like that, it always helps to mention them in the question.

Comment: off-topic: where possible `ast.literal_eval` is preferred instead of `eval` as it only evaluates: 'strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None'

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume an array as arr

Method 1: First sorting an array in ascending order & then printing the element of 0 index

```
arr = [2,5,1,3,0]
arr.sort()
print(arr[0])
```

Method 2: Using For loop until we get the smallest number then min

```
arr = [2,5,1,3,0]
min = arr[0]
for i in range (len(arr)):
    if arr[i] < min:
        min = arr[i]
print(min)
```

Comment: Concerning method 1: A) it is an in-place operation, use `sort` build-in for a new list B) using a sort approach to find only the min/max could be a waste since, depending on the data in the list, it is at worst an _n*log(n)_