# Trying to shorten my python code. Does anyone have an idea?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code works fine. I originally tried to set smallest=zero but this skipped 18. I added None. Now my code works great. However, I would like to shorten my code if there is a shorter way to write this. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks!

```
age = [18, 23,43,23,19,23,43,43,23,45,53,52,43,54,34,23,43]

smallest = None
for i in age:
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = i
        print(smallest)
    elif i < smallest:
        smallest = i
        print(smallest)
```

Comment: `smallest = min(age)`

Comment: With the data given, this will print only the first number because it happens to be the minimum. If the first number doesn't happen to be the minimum, though, it will print all the intermediate values of `smallest` on its way to finding the minimum. Is that behavior intended?

Comment: Hi Fred, Thanks for your response. I'm trying to find the absolute minimum regardless of its position in the set. And I was practicing for loops, so I would like to run through the list and hold on to the minimum value while through the values from left to right. Hopefully, that makes sense.

Comment: It sounds to me like you should not be printing `smallest` within the loop, then. Using `min(age)` is really the right way to go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smallest number in an array python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979908/smallest-number-in-an-array-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just call `min()`

```py
age = [18, 23,43,23,19,23,43,43,23,45,53,52,43,54,34,23,43]
print(f"The min age is:{min(age)}")
```

`The min age is:18`

You can read more about `min()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)

Comment: Wow, you are fast. This is fantastic. Thanks! I'm new to Python, and I am practicing for loops. Is there a shorter for loop I could use to shorten this code?

Answer (score 1):

If all you really want is the minimum number, using `min()` is the way to go.

If you do really want to print each smallest value so far (why??) you could combine your cases into one using `or`:

```
age = [18, 23,43,23,19,23,43,43,23,45,53,52,43,54,34,23,43]

smallest = None
for i in age:
    if smallest is None or i < smallest:
        smallest = i
        print(smallest)
```

It makes no difference if the first value happens to be the smallest, but if you move the 18 somewhere else in the list, it will change the output.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you to make this code shorter.

My code is:

```
age = [18, 23,43,23,19,23,43,43,23,45,53,52,43,54,34,23,43]
age.sort()
print(age[0])
```

I first sorted the list in ascending order with the sort function.

Then I just printed the first element of the sorted list.

Your output is 18. My code is also giving an output of 18.

Comment: do you know that using `min` is better then using `sort`