# if (the element that has index [0] in a list) is the smallest number in the list : print("x") How can i retype this in python?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to type a code that return diferent string messeges depending on the place of the smallest number in a list. for example .. if the smallest number in the list has index [0] so i want him to print "x" .... and if the smallest number has index [1] so i want him to print "y" ..... and so on

I tried the next code but it is not working correctly ...... any explanation please?

```
list1 = [5, 2, 3]

if list1[0] is min(list1):
    print("it is x")
elif list1[1] is min(list1):
    print("it is y")
elif list1[2] is min(list1):
    print("it is z")
```

Comment: You should use `==`, not `is`.  That said, this code works fine for me.  The `==`/`is` difference might bite you with other types of data, though!

Comment: @Samwise that won't fix whatever the problem is - it would only matter if there were duplicates in the list (and all the relevant values are interned anyway in the OP's example).

Comment: Thank you heheh it is working now

Comment: You can use shorter method: `print(min(zip([5, 2, 3], "xyz"))[1])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smallest number in an array python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979908/smallest-number-in-an-array-python)